# devuelve true o false dependiendo de si el número es simétrico o no

Tags: javascript

function numeroSimetrico() {
// La funcion llamada 'numeroSimetrico' recibe como argumento un numero entero 'num'
// Esta devuelve true o false dependiendo de si el número es simétrico o no.
// Un número es simétrico cuando es igual a su reverso.
// Ej:
**// numeroSimetrico(11711) devuelve true**

// Tu código:

Comment: Hola, ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Entonces es todo? Simplemente copiastes y pegastes tu ejercicio

Answer (score -1):

Lo más sencillo que me viene a la cabeza, utilizando un **Array** y el método **reverse()**.

Convertimos el número a una cadena de texto, luego la dividimos en un array, invertimos el orden de elementos y los unimos a una cadena de texto, y al final las comparamos si son iguales o no. Las palabras y números "simétricas" como dice se llaman palíndromas, es una tarea bien común para aprender JavaScript.

```js
const num1 = 11711;
const num2 = 12711;

function numeroSimetrico(num) {
  return ""+num === (""+num).split("").reverse().join("")
}

console.log(numeroSimetrico(num1))
console.log(numeroSimetrico(num2))
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta puede responder a la pregunta, debes tener en cuenta que le estas resolviendo el ejercicio sin mas y eso no es el objetivo del sitio

Comment: @JuanRivera de acuerdo, a ver si mira el código y aprende algo, he intentado ponerle una explicación que le quede más claro lo que se hace la función

Comment: Lee [answer]: procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad y que ni siquiera demuestran que el usuario se ha esforzado en por lo menos intentar resolver su problema.